# Why do I have to supply function as a first argument to Apache Spark RDD.sortBy in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to sort an RDD[Double] in Scala and I get an error if I don't supply a function as a first argument. In other cases where I had an RDD[(String, Double)], it made sense to me to provide a function for the sorting so that Spark knew which values to use for the sorting:

[image: scala code sorting an RDD[(String, Double)] without error highlight]

But if my RDD just contains Doubles, why do I need to specify a function, if the values are already of a type that support ordering. The IDE highlights an error, that only goes away if I provide a dummy function that basically returns the same value it receives:

[image: scala code gets error highlight when I don't pass a function]

Why does this happen? Do I need to supply that dummy function even if it is unnecessary?

As you can see in the image, I tried different approaches. The first two work because I'm passing a function. The first one returns the same value. The second one converts the value (which is already a Double) to a Double (IDE highlights this as redundant, but if I delete it, the error comes back).

The last two is me trying to get the code to work without highlighting the error. I guess for the first one I'm trying to tell the compiler to use the RDD as is, without a transform function. The second one is just not receiving that first argument that it wants.

Maybe the problem is my inability to tell the compiler to use the RDD as it comes + my not good understanding of Scala's implicit parameters and Ordering system.

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Copy/paste the actual code in your original post. Images are impossible to search for or copy to reproduce.

Comment: Because the method you are calling is generic, it doesn't know if it will be called on a `RDD[Double]`, or a `RDD[(String, Double)]` or a `RDD[SomeComplexClass]`, so it is defined as `def sortBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit ev: Order[B]): RDD[A]`. Sure, they could add another function like `sorted` for this case, but that doesn't mean `sortBy` would not require a function.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as pictures of text. This is a website for programmers, not painters. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because that's how the Spark RDD API is designed. It's mandatory to provide a sorting function.

Usually (in other collections APIs) you find a `sort` or `sorted` method that doesn't need a sorting function but Spark's RDD doesn't have this.

---

That being said, the idiomatic way to achieve you want would be to use the existing `identity` function:

```scala
someRdd.sortBy(identity)
```